# Select an item that has an href in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a file manager where you can edit files in bulk but I can't get the select function to work.

I'm using this [Cute File Browser](http://tutorialzine.com/2014/09/cute-file-browser-jquery-ajax-php/). I have given my `ul` element an id and added this script to the page :

```
$("#test li").click(function() {
    alert(this.id); // get id of clicked li
});
```

But when I click on an item, it opens its url instead of selecting it.

Answer (score 2):

Possible have to use the link element and use `e.preventDefault();`

```
$("#test li a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).parent().id); // get id of clicked li
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: another helpful thing to look at it, if this doesn't solve it, since it's hard to tell without any html is event.stopPropagation();

Comment: http://173.214.171.215/ thas the adress where its running on if you want you can take a look @ray-suelzer

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default behaviour of navigating to the clicked url **and, if your element is added dynamically, you'll need to use event delegation with jquery's `.on()'`**:

**Edit** added the use of jQuery UI's `dialog()` to get you started on changing the name for your file. of course you'll have to modify `modifyFile()` to actually update the files on your server

I copied the html below from the inspector while looking at the page you provided. One thing I noticed id that all of your generated li elements have the same id of "1". You'll need to fix that. Ids must be unique whatever is generating your li elements should give them each a unique `id`.

```js
$(function() {
    var dialog, form,

        dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Submit Changes": function() {
                    var newName = $('#newName').val(); // don't forget to do some checks on the value here
                    modifyFile(newName, dialog);
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    dialog.dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function() {
                form[0].reset();
            }
        });

    form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var newName = $('#newName').val(); // don't forget to do some checks on the value here
        modifyFile(newName, dialog);
    });


    $(document).on('click', '#test li', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#newName').val(this.id); // get id of clicked li
        dialog.dialog("open");
    });

});

function modifyFile(newName, dialog) {
    // do stuff with your new name here like update it on your server
    alert('File name changed to: ' + newName);
    dialog.dialog("close");

}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul class="data animated" id="test" style="">
  <li class="files" id="1">
   <a href="Downloads/chipzel-Super-HexagonEP(2012)[FLAC]/01-Courtesy.flac" title="Downloads/chipzel-Super-HexagonEP(2012)[FLAC]/01-Courtesy.flac" class="files">
     <span class="icon file f-flac">.flac</span><span class="name">01-Courtesy.flac</span> 
        <span class="details">17 MB</span>
    </a> 
  </li>
  <li class="files" id="1">
   <a href="Downloads/chipzel-Super-HexagonEP(2012)[FLAC]/02-Otis.flac" title="Downloads/chipzel-Super-HexagonEP(2012)[FLAC]/02-Otis.flac" class="files">
     <span class="icon file f-flac">.flac</span><span class="name">02-Otis.flac</span> 
        <span class="details">18 MB</span>
    </a> 
  </li>
  <li class="files" id="1">
   <a href="Downloads/chipzel-Super-HexagonEP(2012)[FLAC]/03-Focus.flac" title="Downloads/chipzel-Super-HexagonEP(2012)[FLAC]/03-Focus.flac" class="files">
    <span class="icon file f-flac">.flac</span><span class="name">03-Focus.flac</span> 
        <span class="details">21 MB</span>
    </a> 
  </li>
  <li class="files" id="1"> 
   <a href="Downloads/chipzel-Super-HexagonEP(2012)[FLAC]/cover.jpg" title="Downloads/chipzel-Super-HexagonEP(2012)[FLAC]/cover.jpg" class="files">
      <div style="display:inline-block;margin:20px 30px 0px 25px;border-radius:8px;width:60px;height:70px;background-position: center center;background-size: cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;background-image: url(Downloads/chipzel-Super-HexagonEP(2012)[FLAC]/cover.jpg);"></div>
     <span class="name">cover.jpg</span> <span class="details">296 KB</span> 
    </a> 
  </li>
  <li class="files" id="1">
   <a href="Downloads/chipzel-Super-HexagonEP(2012)[FLAC]/whatpub.txt" title="Downloads/chipzel-Super-HexagonEP(2012)[FLAC]/whatpub.txt" class="files">
     <span class="icon file f-txt">.txt</span><span class="name">whatpub.txt</span> 
        <span class="details">481 Bytes</span>
    </a> 
  </li>
</ul>




<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
   <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name">New File Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="newName" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"> 
      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: @RaySuelzer see the image I've added above, this does work. The link is not opened

Comment: @Nicolai can we see your html?

Comment: sure this is the link http://173.214.171.215/ 
and this is in the index file and scan file http://pastebin.com/2gC75018

Comment: Possible chrome differ from other browser, but if you add 'event.stopPropagation();' like @RaySuelzer already mentioned, I could imagine it works also.

Comment: @Nicolai it looks like your `li` elements are added dynamically, please see my edit above

Comment: @skroczek I just tested it in firefox, chrome, IE 10, and safari all work. I'm not saying that `stopPropagation();` or even that it's not a prefered method, just that this doesn't seem to be the OP's issue

Comment: @DelightedD0D ths it work it give a blank alerts but thats normal i gues so now how can i make it the i can change the name of slected file do you have any tips ?

Comment: @Nicolai the alert should only be empty if the element you are clicking on has no `id` attribute. I copied the html from the inspector while looking at the page you provided. One thing I noticed id that all of your generated li elements have the same `id`  of "1". You'll need to fix that. Ids must be unique what ever is generating your `li` elements is flawed. As for changing the file names, my edit above should get you started.

Comment: @Nicolai How you actually update the files on your server will depend on how you are storing them. You'll probably want to use something like an `ajax`  call to a `php` script to do that part.

Comment: @Nicolai one last thing, Im not sure why you want the id of the element, seems like you might really want the file name itself. I figured you had a reason for needing it though so I used it to fill in the input filed for the file name. Im sure that's not really what you wanted it for though